# C | find the size of the value a void Pointer is pointing at using sizeof()

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof, void, void-pointers

Im trying to use sizeof() to find the size of the value a void pointer is pointing at, I want to use it to print the value.

this code

```
    int num = 5;
    void *voidPtr;
    voidPtr = &num;
    printf("%d", sizeof(*voidPtr));
```

Prints, 1.
How can i get it to print 4?

If theres any other way to print the value of the void pointer, please let me know

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't - all you're going to get is the `sizeof(void)`

Comment: @ChrisTurner it is gcc extension https://godbolt.org/z/MP4eeGrb5

Comment: This is kind of like asking, "Given the address 123 Main Street, how can I figure out from the address how many square feet the building there has?"  But, obviously, you can't do this — that's not what street addresses are for.

Comment: @SteveSummit Nice idea but it's not really the same because based on the address you _can_ find out the number of square feet, by going there or checking records, because the address identifies the building. A better comparison would be something like "Given the birthdate of somebody, how can I find out at what age they died?" in my opinion.

Comment: Most pointers (`int *`, `float *`, `char *`) carry with them the type of the pointed-to object, and this directly implies the size of the pointed-to object.  But void pointers are quite different, and deliberately so.  You use `void *` when you do *not* know the type of the pointed-to object.  But it is, therefore, quite impossible to determine the size of the pointed-to object — it's just a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @CherryDT Right.  And if you keep some separate data structure somewhere, you can keep track of the size of the pointed-to object, too!  (Or, at least, that's what I was imagining when I constructed the analogy.  That is, "checking records" is not so far from what `free()` does when it figures out, based on the pointer value you give it, how much to free.)

Comment: @SteveSummit I find this is a not a great example. Obviously, one can find the size of the property given it's address quite easily.

Comment: @SergeyA Obviously?  Easily?  So tell me: how many square feet *is* the building at 123 Main Street? :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit which state/town? (Complete address would include this)

Comment: @SergeyA We probably don't have to take this any further — arguing by analogy is always dangerous, because it only works if everyone shares the same assumptions — but I did say, "how can I figure out *from the address*", implying that using some external database wasn't kosher.  But if you want a reasonable challenge, and if you don't mind my changing the address on you, you can try to tell me the square footage of 316 Pearl St., Cambridge, MA, US, Terra, Sol.  I will settle for the square footage of either the lot or the house on it. :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit I do agree with your statement in full. Being a good sport ;), I'd say, the aforementioned property is a 2-story building with attic, lot size being 4500 sq ft, there are two units in the building, and the total living area is about 2300 sq ft?

Comment: @SergeyA *Very* good.  (I might add that, although official, the database you found that information in is rather badly misleading.  The overall condition of that building isn't "poor", it's *derelict*, and has been so for as long as I've lived in the neighborhood.  But this is increasingly off-topic, so I'll stop now.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of pointer merely conveys the starting address of an object, not any information about its size.

The type of a pointer inherently conveys information about the size of the object it points to, if it is a complete type. However, `void` is incomplete, and a `void *` provides no information about the size of the object it originated from (except possibly by extensions to standard C and by debugging features).

Generally, if your program needs to know the size of what a `void *` points to, it must track that information itself.

Answer (score 5):

1. `*voidPtr` is invalid in standard C. It is a GCC extension and that is the reason why `sizeof(*voidptr)` is `1`. Any other (non GCC family) compiler will not compile this code.
2. `%d` is the wrong format to print `size_t`. You should use `%zu` instead.
3. There is no way in C to determine what size object is referenced by the `void` pointer

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya t does. It explains why it prints `1`.  I suggest you to write own answer

Comment: Technically speaking, the OPs question is "How can i get it to print 4?" but we all know that is not likely the desired information. But I do like Ayay's response, since it addresses the trouble code to begin with.

Comment: @icodeplenty point 3 explains that it is not possible, thus it is impossible to advice how to print 4

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, "it can't be done" is a valid answer to such a question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the 3rd point that was added later makes it an answer now. So I will delete my comment

Answer (score 4):

The type `void` is an incomplete type. It means that the size of an expression of the type `void` is undefined.

From the C Standard (6.2.5 Types)

> 19 The void type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete
> object type that cannot be completed

and (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 1 The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
> function type or an incomplete type, ...

Some compilers for back compatibility make `sizeof( void )` equal to `sizeof( char )` that is to `1`.

If you need to get the size of the pointed object using a pointer of the type `void *` then you need to cast the pointer to the pointer of the referenced object type as for example

```
printf("%zu", sizeof( *( int * )voidPtr));
```

Pay attention to that you need to use the conversion specifier `%zu` with expressions of the type `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you think for this:

```
printf( "%d", sizeof voidPtr );
```

It is the size of `voidPtr` variable, not the pointed value `*voidPtr`. `sizeof voidPtr` will be 4 if program is compiled as 32-bit. PS: `sizeof` does not need parenthesis when used with variable/object, not type. E.g. `sizeof MyVariable` vs `sizeof (long)`.

Answer (score -1):

You said, "I'm trying to find the size of the value a void pointer is pointing at", is pointing to an integer in your code, so use this:

```c
printf("%d", sizeof(int));
```

Understand that 'sizeof()' must know the type at compile time.

Comment: sizeof is not always evaluated compile time. Here it is calculated run time https://godbolt.org/z/oTPbMscbY

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: I interpret the question to be asking how to determine the size of the pointed-to object **based on the pointer**.  It is not particularly interesting or useful to rely on knowing *a priori* what object the pointer points to.